# Is it possible to assign List<string> to EditorGUILayout.TextField()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a sub category using unity custom editor and scriptableobject. But I'm getting an error when assigning it to an editorGUILayout.TextField(). Or is there a better way of doing this?
Thanks.

ScriptableObject

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Category : ScriptableObject
{
    public string id;
    public string category;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class SubCatData
    {
        public List<string> subcategory;
    }
    public List<SubCatData> subCat = new List<SubCatData>();
}
```

Assigning subcategory to a EditorGUILayout.TextField().

```
category.subCat[i].subcategory = EditorGUILayout.TextField(category.subCat[i].subcategory);
```

I get this error:

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption'
```

EDIT

I think it doesn't recognize it as a string. But when I change it to

`category.subCat[i].subcategory = EditorGUILayout.TextField("");`

I get this error.

`Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'`

Comment: Did you try to use a constructor of EditorGUILayout.Textfield like described here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.TextField.html
and than assign it to the subcategory?
If you do not need line breaks (would be another question how to achieve that), you could use that propably.

Comment: How can you assign a **string** to a **list of string**? you should assign a string to **one of** a list of string.

Comment: Thanks @shingo you are right. I forgot to loop through the list of subcategory. It must be {category.subCat[i].subcategory[index]}. Maybe I'm just too tired of coding that I got confused. Please make it as an answer.